# Definition of SSH identity

Tags: ssh

I'm reading through https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config , trying to get a better understanding of the ssh process and options. with reference to the

```
IdentitiesOnly eg(`IdentitiesOnly=yes` )
```

is the 'Identity' referring to a public-private key pair and excluding password based ssh authentication? what is being excluded by 'Only'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the 'Identity' referring to a public-private key pair and exclusing password based ssh authentication?

It is clearly explained in the manual pages. It means that only the private keys listed in the configuration file (option to list PK is called `IdentityFile`). It does not modify the behaviour for the password authentication, as you can simply verify:

```
$ ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes localhost
jakuje@localhost's password:
```

> what is being excluded by 'Only'?

It is just the reference to already mentioned `IdentityFile` and saying that it should not use any other keys then the ones specified using the above options. What is excluded are the other keys provided by `ssh-agent`.